# $f$ is continuous on $X$ iff $f$ is continuous on every compact subset

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space,then prove that $f$  is continuous on $X$ iff $f$ is continuous on every compact subset of $X$.

If $f$ is continuous on $X$ then its restriction on each compact subset will be continuous, and conversely if $f$ is continuous on each compact set then for $x\in X$ the set $\{x\}$ is compact and thus $f$ must be continuous at $x$ , as $x$ was arbitrary $f$ will be continuous on $X$.

Comment: No, the restriction of _every_ function on any space to a singleton $\{x\}$ is continuous, that doesn't tell you anything about the continuity of $f$. You need to use the sequence criterion for continuity.

Comment: conversely, since $X$ is a compact subset of $X$ it is trivial.

Comment: @DanielFischer For the forward part I assumed $f$ to be continuous and then since restriction function is continuous so it will be continuous on every compact subset of $X$

Comment: @pqnet $X$ is not given to be compact!

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal I was referring to the "conversely ... the set $\{x\}$ is compact and thus $f$ must be continuous at $x$". That is wrong.

Comment: @DanielFischer okay now I got your point.

Comment: @DanielFischer one thing I'm not getting is why my argument is wrong?

Comment: Continuity is a property that looks at the behaviour of a function in a neighbourhood of a point, not only at the value of the function at the point. If you restrict the function to $\{x\}$, you get only the value at $x$, nothing about the behaviour of $f$ near that point [unless $x$ is an isolated point, when there are no other points "near" $x$, then $\{x\}$ _is_ a neighbourhood of $x$, and $f$ is continuous at $x$].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** $f$ is continuous if for every convergent sequence $x_n \to x$ in $X$, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.  Consider the set
$$
\{x_n : n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \} \subset X
$$

Comment: The set you mentioned is compact and as $f$ is continuous on this set, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: You've got the right idea, now just prove those statements.  In particular, how do you know the set is compact?

Comment: If I take any open cover covering the set then the open set covering $\lim x_n$ will contain a tail of the $\{x_n\}$ and thus we can extract a finite subcover.

Comment: There you go! That should do it.  Looks good.