# continuity on compact subsets implies continuity

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Consider this problem: Let $(X,d)$,$(Y,\rho)$ be two metric spaces (no further hypothesis). Prove a function $f:(X,d)\rightarrow (Y,\rho)$ is continuous if and only if for every compact $K\subseteq X$ the restriction of $f$ on $K$ is continuous.

Now the => part is fairly simple since the restriction of a continuous function is also continuous. 
What about the <= part?
If we choose a convergent sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$ we need only show $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$, but how does compactness come into play?

Comment: $\{x_n \mid n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{x\}$ is compact.

Comment: google: "continuous on every compact subset", result: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915096/f-is-continuous-on-x-iff-f-is-continuous-on-every-compact-subset

Comment: I couldn't find that question, it's exactly what I am asking. Thanks!